# Test Orchestrator Sample

Tags: android, android-testing, android-junit

Is anyone aware of a sample project that shows how to get test orchestrator working?  I checked the google samples and there doesn't seem to be a good sample project that shows test orchestrator.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing

I have been attempting to get android tests running in the test orchestrator but have been struggling to get it to work correctly.  I tried both running the tests through Android Studio (latest 3.2.1) as well as the command line (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-command-line).  I used the Android developer document for reference.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner

Here are the steps I followed.

```
1) Create an empty activity application using the wizard in Android 
Studio 
2) Enable the test orchestrator using the steps provided here 
(https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner).
3) Run the unit tests from within the IDE and from the command line.
```

When I do this, I get an error indicating that my "test suite is empty".  I get the same error running from command-line.

Note that if I run the test without test orchestrator, then the test runs successfully.

Also note that I am using the latest test orchestrator versions

- test-orchestrator (https://maven.google.com/androidx/test/orchestrator/1.1.0/orchestrator-1.1.0.apk)
- test-services (https://maven.google.com/androidx/test/services/test-services/1.1.0/test-services-1.1.0.apk)

Comment: Are you using 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR' (with X) in your build.gradle?

Comment: Thanks @tobltobs.  This was my problem :) For some reason the sample I looked at had the "X" missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete configuration to run test orchestrator:

1. Add dependencies:

   androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$testRunner"
   androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:$testOrchestrator"
2. Add clear package instruction (within *defaultConfig* in app's build.gradle):

   //allows run all tests on an isolated way. If we need to debug a test, should disable this and the orchestrator
       testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
3. Add to testOptions Android/AndroidX orchestrator:

   testOptions {
       execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
   }